# Equivalent of having 2 projects open in my WebStorm workspace?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I open a project, but want to create a module to reference in WebStorm, (mostly so I can do work in 2 projects instead of having 2+ instance of WebStorm open).

In IntelliJ Ultimate or whatnot, it has a modules button. It Kinda looks like modules does not exist for me, or at least I have not see anything.

I have 2 folders which are siblings to each other representing the 2 separate projects I wanted to open in 1 instance of WebStorm.

Where can I find this information for WebStorm?

A lot of the googling was talking about modules but I didn't see that option, and I believe I noticed some posts mentioning this is not a thing in WebStorm.

Thoughts?  Guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebStorm/PhpStorm project consists of a **single module only** (`WEB_MODULE` type).

---

WebStorm cannot open more than one project in single frame. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7968 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

At the same time it's possible in PhpStorm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/opening-multiple-projects.html#d197136e31

But it's still will not be full "two *separate* projects with separate settings" AFAIK. It's more of a "attaching 2nd project so you can see and edit those files in the same frame".

---

Question is: why exactly you need this? To access files of a second project? If so -- just add such folder(s) as Additional Content Root -- it will be listed as another node in the Project View panel and files will be treated as part of the project itself.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-content-roots.html

Answer (score 1):

in Webstrom 2019.2 is it now avilable to open *attached project* to the current project.

> **Open multiple projects in one window**
>   When you have a project opened in WebStorm and want to open another one, you can now attach this second project to the opened one, so that you can see both of them in the same IDE window. If you want to close the attached project, right-click its root in the Project view and select Remove from Project View.
>   https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/